# Load css file into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fetching a css file using $.getscript as below:

```
$.getScript(url, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            alert(data); // Data returned
            console.log(textStatus); // Success
            console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
            console.log("Load was performed.");
        });
```

My requirement is to store the data in textarea.
But im getting error as unexpected token .
How to achieve this?

Comment: can you post that traceback?

Comment: Simple: CSS !== JavaScript; so getScript is useless

Comment: @epascarello then how can i load css into textarea?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code..

```
$.getScript(url, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  alert(data); // Data returned
  console.log(textStatus); // Success
  console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
  console.log("Load was performed.");
  $('textarea').val(data) // <---------- ADD DATA TO TEXTAREA
});
```

**ALTERNATELY,**

You can do it using `.load()` function.

```
$( "textarea" ).load( "path/to/myCss.css", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

You dont *have* to use `$.getScript()`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
$( "textarea" ).load( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Keep it simple. :)

Comment: It throws the error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Well that means it is a different domain and JavaScript can not access different domain.

Comment: i tried your alternate answer also. The data returned is undefined, though the response is success.

Comment: getScript was made to load javascript files and add them to the document that's it, so all getScript must be avoided.

Comment: @manu Please check the path to your CSS. If you can get it to your local machine, you wouldnt get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error, I think. Also, check my updated alternate answer with working code snippet.

Comment: @RahulDesai Your code works for googleapis.com. But it does not work for my css file

Answer (score 1):

try using `.load()` to get it done.Make sure that your file path is correct.

```js
 $( "textarea" ).load("http://cdn.rawgit.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/master/css/colorpicker.css", function() {
    alert( "file loaded in textarea" );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="myTable" border="1" cols="40" rows="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: @cram2208 now check.that was a sample i did not gave the exact path to a file.

Comment: Seems to work pretty well, never knew that'd work, I'll keep that in mind. ^^

Answer (score 0):

you must include script data

```
$.getScript(url, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            alert(data); // Data returned
            console.log(textStatus); // Success
            console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
            console.log("Load was performed.");
        });
```

Comment: Sorry i did not understand

Answer (score 0):

My idea on the subject would be the following:

```
$.get("your css file to load.css", function(data) {
    $("your textarea selector").val(data);
});
```

Your code doesn't work because getScript will automatically consider the data to be script/javascript data and so will load it as such. On the other hand, using get will load the data as required and you simply set the textarea value with it.

Also, if you want to manage cases in which the file wouldn't load, instead of using jqxhr.status you can also rely on built-in AJAX jQuery handler such as: done (status 200), fail (error 404, 500, etc.), always (any status, perfom whether the file loads successfully or not). Additionnally, the function defined by default after your file path in "get" is like a "done" handler.

Cheers,